# Pass variadic args through dispatch_async block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, variadic-functions

Is there a way to pass variadic args into a dispatch async block ? In others words can I pass my va_list into the disatch_async block ?

Something like this

```
void someFunction (NSObject * format, ...)
{
  va_list argList;
  va_start(argList, format);
  dispatch_async(some_queue(), ^{  
    // Use it here
  });
  va_end(argList);
}
```

Or like this

```
void someFunction (NSObject * format, ...)
{

  dispatch_async(some_queue(), ^{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);  
    // Use it here
    va_end(argList);
  });

}
```

A work around is to make it an objet before the dispatch so that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to pass the arguments in an `NSArray` object?

Comment: Unless `someFunction` is not returned before the block code called, or the address of parameter is meaningless and dangerous.

Comment: I don't need to. Pass an object works fine and it is probably the right thing to do. I just wonder if it is possible maybe it is not, so far I do not found a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`va_start` will keep its first parameter's(`format`) address in `va_list`(argList) and then fetch other parameters through moving pointer, but if the function(`someFunction`) returned, the memory of that address will be override at any time, so it is dangerous to access its values and the result is undefined.

```
va_list argList;
va_start(argList, format);  
// Use it here
va_end(argList);
```

Comment: So the answer is no, that what I thought. Thanks. I'll validate later if nobody disagrees with you.

Comment: Yes, you should fetch these parameters with `va_arg` before `dispatch_async...`

Comment: Probably the number of args is dynamic, so he can catch them, but not pass them.